# Unable to Parse a date string to timestamp in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, date, select, google-bigquery

I have date string column in my dataset and this date string column has date values in the formats as shown below

Some dates are in the format : 2020-04-22 and 
some dates are in the format : 04/22/2020

Kindly suggest how to parse these date values to a timestamp format : 2020-04-22 00:00:00 UTC

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to normalise both dates.
Try using:

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%F', your_date_field), SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', your_date_field)) AS your_new_date_field
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If all strings strictly conform to one format or the other, you can do conditional logic:

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP(
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(mydate, r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" THEN "%F"
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(mydate, r"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$" THEN "%m/%d/%Y"
    END,
    mydate
)
```

You might want to use `SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `PARSE_TIMESTAMP()` to prevent conversion failures on unmatched formats.

Comment: Thanks so much GMB for your response! It is working with a small change in the logic.  Missing closing paranthesis.  Anyways it really helped. PARSE_TIMESTAMP(
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(mydate, r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" )THEN "%F"
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(mydate, r"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$" ) THEN "%m/%d/%Y"
    END,
    mydate
)